# MySQL Group by query over multiple primary key table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm having problem with GROUP BY query in a specific table which has two column primary key.

My table looks like like this:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stocks` (
      `id_city` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `id_prod` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `sell_price` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_city`,`id_prod`)
    )
```

Let's say it has such values inserted:

```
INSERT INTO `stocks` (`id_city`, `id_prod`, `sell_price`) 
VALUES ('1', '1', '100'), ('2', '1', '90'), ('3', '1', '10');
```

After such query:

```
SELECT id_prod, id_city, MIN(sell_price)
            FROM stocks 
            GROUP BY id_prod
```

the result row looses 'id_city' key - it takes the first occurance of city_id,

```
id_prod     id_city     MIN(sell_price)
1           1           10
```

How to build a proper query for this case? The result should look like this:

```
id_prod     id_city     MIN(sell_price)
1           3           10
```

Comment: what represent the number 3 ? the last id or the count if id_city ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the record that holds the `min(sell_price)` you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT s1.id_prod, 
  s1.id_city, 
  s1.sell_price
FROM stocks s1
inner join
(
  select id_prod,  MIN(sell_price) sell_price
  from stocks
  group by id_prod
) s2
  on s1.id_prod = s2.id_prod
  and s1.sell_price = s2.sell_price
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/131c2/3)

This returns:

```
| ID_PROD | ID_CITY | SELL_PRICE |
----------------------------------
|       1 |       3 |         10 |
```

Comment: Great! Is it only workaround or just my query cannot be done with 'group by'?

Comment: Not in your situation. If you `GROUP BY` only the `ID_PROD`, then there is no guarantee as to what `id_city` will be returned. You cannot `GROUP BY id_city` since you would return all 3 records because they are distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like that using `max(id_city)`

```
    SELECT id_prod, max(id_city) city , MIN(sell_price)
        FROM stocks 
        GROUP BY id_prod
```

[**sql demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9aa0/8)

or like that using `count(id_city)`

```
     SELECT id_prod, count(id_city) city, MIN(sell_price)
        FROM stocks 
        GROUP BY id_prod
```

[**sql demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9aa0/7)

both returns

```
  ID_PROD   CITY    MIN(SELL_PRICE)
      1        3                10
```

**EDIT**

try this by `INNER JOIN`

```
   SELECT s.id_prod, 
          s.id_city, 
          s.sell_price
   FROM stocks s
   inner join
             (
              select id_prod,  MIN(sell_price) sell_price
              from stocks
               group by id_prod
              ) s1
     on s.id_prod = s1.id_prod
     and s.sell_price = s1.sell_price
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86bd0/2)

Comment: No. I want to return 'id_city' which has lowest 'sell_price' for certain products.

Comment: Now it works fine. Looks almost the same as @bluefeet ;). Thanks for both answers!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add `id_city` to the `GROUP BY` clause as well

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: This would return all record separated by id_city. I want to have ONE record with lowest price for product with proper id_city.

Comment: in that case, see @bluefeet answer. That is spot on I believe